# Unspecified error in Delphi twain

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, twain

I have a program created with Delphi XE2 and want to scan images from a Flatbed scanner. I use `TDelphiTwain` and on my computer everything works fine.

The target is a touch-screen device with MS Windows Embedded for POS on, and there I constantly get an 'Unspecified error' when I click on the button to open the form. The strange thing is, **it has worked before on this device** and I haven't changed a thing. Suddenly it stopped working on that device.

Scanning in Windows works. I reinstalled the drivers, but that doesn't make a difference.

I have another touch-device with Windows XP embedded on it and even there it is still working fine.

Disconnecting the flatbed and trying to open the form gives an 'access violation exception'.

I have no idea how to debug this or where to look, as it works on my PC perfectly.

Comment: @sir-rufo, why did you delete the DelphiTwain tag?

Comment: because I added the `delphi` tag and nearly all people are looking for `delphi` and/or `twain` tag because they are commonly used and expected to tag the questions.

Comment: This does sound like a driver issue. Anything in Event Viewer?

Comment: Try with TwainKit and see what happens http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/files/?source=navbar

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: No, nothing in Event Viewer. Drivers have also crossed my mind, but the scanner works when using the Windows Scanning wizard.

Comment: @Graymatter: I tried it, but the app does not recognize my scanner. It detects a Canon device but my scanner is a HP. Trying to prcoeed does not work.

Comment: **UPDATE**: I removed the canon drivers, that was the previous scanner but not in use anymore. Now the app still doesn't recognize my HP scanner.
Error in my application stays the same.

Comment: There is a set of drivers for the HP called "Commercial Twain Driver". I have had problems with other drivers but never that one.

Comment: Now I installed the Full Feature Software and Driver instead of the Basic Driver and now the app @Graymatter suggested works! Mine still gives the same error.
I googled on Commercial Twain Driver but did not find something useful.

Comment: I found this the other day, I might give it a shot when there is more time.
=> http://www.kluug.net/delphitwain.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out the problem is NOT Twain, but working with the PDF-ActiveX component...
And it seems I'm not the only one. => [How do I get Acrobat Reader Imported into Delphi 2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497990/how-do-i-get-acrobat-reader-imported-into-delphi-2007)

On the modern devices, Adobe Reader 11.0.0.7 installs and everything works. But some older devices fail while installing this version, and I have to go back to version 8.1.1 to get past the setup, but not being compatible for the ActiveX.

If we change code to get it working with older versions (like 8.1.1), it fails with Adobe Reader 11.0.0.7

some more lecture:
https://forums.adobe.com/message/6381248
https://forums.adobe.com/message/6400731

Thanx for thinking and searching with me.